# select value from dropdown not working with explicit wait in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm testing a website using Java and Selenium, and I encounter a problem with timing, on Chrome browser. The automation test runs at an accelerating speed, which I assume causes elements loading  issues. Instead of using Thread.sleep which slows down my test, I tried to implement an explicit wait throughout the infrastructure, but elements still not visible or clickable.
Here is an example of a select value from dropdown element that fails each time.

```
public Select selectByValue(WebElement dropdown, String value) throws Exception {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(dropdown));
    Select select = new Select(dropdown);
    select.selectByVisibleText(value);
    return select;
}
```

I get an exception which states that the element is not visible, however it works perfectly when using debug mode or putting a line of code before: Thread.sleep(4000).
How can I wait for the element to appear and load properly before interacting? without putting sleep commands which slows down my test.

Comment: Without site an element locator it's hard to say what is happening in your case.

Comment: The locator is ok, it’s id. I have many places it fails, where it worked on Explorer browser which was slow. Also works on Chrome when I debug i

Comment: Without resource + element locator it's impossible to identify your issue. Question needs debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to answer without a LOT of specifics. Often the Threat.sleep(1000) command is the simplest solution to the problem.

It's important to always remember the reasoning behind the tests. It's not always essential for Selenium tests to run at the speed of light. It's generally fairly acceptable for these kinds of test to run slower, so personally I wouldn't really worry too much about this stuff if it's still running at an acceptable pace.

A lot of these challenges come from the way the UIs have been designed and built. Adding in the waits often are the only viable solution to have as a buffer for the services behind the scenes you are working with.

Unfortunately not a 100% reliable solution for any situation, just the nature of how everything plugs together under the hood.

Comment: Yea, I understand. But the issue that bothers me is the idea that using Thread.sleep is not quite recommended, and a bit of frustration because I use explicit wait correctly

Comment: Yup. Been through that same frustration myself in the past. It is a tad annoying. Often caused by API driven front ends that dynamically load data for certain elements through JavaScript. It's just one of those quirky things we have to deal with.